# Do rules of inference in first order logic require to be in a meta theory, and does this have something deeper related to incompleteness?

Tags: logic

Is it impossible to encode the rules (for example, modus pones) in the object language itself as axioms instead of rules(or axiom schema?) in a meta language with a model/interpretation?

Just to elaborate in simple propositional logic,

If P, then Q

P

Therefore, Q

There is nothing in the object language that explains the relationship between the statements. I suspect there must be some meta-level statements to relate the object statements. I need to use something like a truth table for instance to see the relations between possible values and realize that the conclusion must be true when all the premises are true.

And this entailment seems like a meta level analog to the material conditional in the object language. So does using this meta level variation of implication give us the deductive power?

And if the above is true, even though I believe that's not what Godel's first incompleteness theorem exactly says, is there something fundamentally deeper going on that relates the two?

Comment: See L.Carroll's [What the Tortoise Said to Achilles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_the_Tortoise_Said_to_Achilles): we need rules to "maipulate" formulas of the object language and those rules cannot be part of the object language itself.

Comment: No connection with [GIT](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/).

Comment: Also [schemata](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/schema/) are "recipes" expressed in the meta-language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that you always need a metatheory, even if just an informal one, in order to define and prove things about logical systems (or any other mathematical objects). This is just an observation about the nature of mathematical reasoning. If you have no logical framework to start with, you have no tools to define one into existence.

A sufficiently expressive formal system *can* represent itself. This isn't too surprising, because you just need to express some rules for manipulating strings of symbols. The system can't literally refer to itself (since it is an object in the metalanguage), but it can make statements about its own internal object that behaves in the same way.

Godel's first theorem says that if the system can represent itself in this way (which actually only requires modeling integer arithmetic), and its deductive steps are algorithmically checkable, and it is consistent (proves no contradictions), then there are statements it can neither prove nor refute. This means that even *after* we've formalized a system $S$ for deducing mathematical facts, we will still encounter mathematical questions *in the language of $S$* that can only be answered in a different system. (One such question is "Is '$S$' consistent?", by Godel's second theorem.)

I think this is more interesting and concrete than the (seemingly unformalizable) observation that we need to use logic to define logic. The two ideas have a superficial similarity, but as far as I can tell, it's not a deep connection.